# Anonymous function implementation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, anonymous-function

So, I am learning about anonymous functions in dart which I know helps to reduce and simplify the code when passing a function as an argument to another function. Now, what I want to know is how exactly is this used in building an application using flutter. I am here seeking some practical implementation in actual flutter applications.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you wanted to implement a `CustomButton` to reuse it across your entire app. In that case, it typically makes sense for it to return a callback function and handle the event where the button is being used. To do so, you pass an `onPressed` function to the button, which will be invoked by the button's internal `onPressed` function.

```dart
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomButton({
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.title,
  });

  final void Function() onPressed;
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Text(title),
    );
  }
}
```

Using it:

```dart
CustomButton(
  onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pageTwo'),
  title: 'Navigate',
)
```

The `CustomButton` can now `push`, `pop`, or do all kinds of things. It is way more flexible than if you implemented a button without a callback function:

```dart
class ForwardButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ForwardButton({
    required this.destination,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String destination;
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, destination),
      child: Text(title),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
ForwardButton(
  destination: '/pageTwo',
  title: 'Navigate',
)
```

If you wanted the `ForwardButton` to do things other than `Navigator.pushNamed`, you'd need to add more logic or arguments to the constructor, and it'll quickly become messy.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this example:

```
final updatedUser = repository.updateUser(
      onError: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text('User could not be updated'),
        ));
      },
      onSuccess: () {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('User updated'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

repository.dart

```
Future<User> updateUser({
    void Function()? onSuccess,
    void Function()? onError,
  }) async {
    final response = await api.updateUser();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      onSuccess?.call();
    }
    if (response.statusCode! < 200 || response.statusCode! > 300) {
      onError?.call();
    }
    return response.data!
  }
```

The repository shouldn't know about anything about a `BuildContext` so we can't show a snackbar right in it.
To show them anyway we can do this in callbacks, using the context of the calling widget.